# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight, wcf, linq

In my silverlight application I am trying to create a database connection using LINQ.
First I add a new LINQ to SQL class, and drag my table called "tblPersoon" into it.

Then in my service file I try to execute the following query:

```
[OperationContract]
public tblPersoon GetPersoonByID(string id)
{
    var query = (from p in tblPersoon where p.id == id select p).Single();
```

But at tblPersoon it gives me the following error.

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'SilverlightApplication1.Web.tblPersoon'.  'Where' not found.

And even when I try the following:

```
var query = (from p in tblPersoon select p).Single();
```

It gives me an error saying 'Select' not found!

Code for the generated class for my table can be found here: http://pastebin.com/edx3XRhi

What is causing this and how would I possibly solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Is the `tblPersoon` implementing `IEnumerable<T>`? You may need to do it using:

```
var query = (from p in tblPersoon.Cast<Person>() select p).Single();
```

This kind of error (*Could not find an implementation of the query pattern*) usually occurs when:

- You are missing LINQ namespace usage (`using System.Linq`)
- Type you are querying does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`

**Edit**:

Apart from fact you query type (`tblPersoon`) instead of property `tblPersoons`, you also need an context instance (class that defines `tblPersoons` property), like this:

```
public tblPersoon GetPersoonByID(string id)
{
    var context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var query = context.tblPersoons.Where(p => p.id == id).Single();
    // ...
```

Comment: My DataClasses1.Desinger.cs (code LINQ auto generates) does not include IEnumerable<T>.

  `public System.Data.Linq.Table<tblPersoon> tblPersoons
  {
   get
   {
    return this.GetTable<tblPersoon>();
   }
  }`

And when I use: var query = (from p in tblPersoon.Cast<Person>() select p).Single(); It gives me the following errors on .Cast. **'SilverlightApplication1.Web.tblPersoon' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'**

Comment: @ThomasSchoof: could it be typo? Property is called `tblPersoons` (note the **s** at the end) while type is `tblPersoon`. You query type, instead of property on type.

Comment: If I try `var query = (from p in tblPersoons select p).Single();` It tells me tblPersoons doesn't even excist.

Comment: The code for the generated class of my table can be found here: http://pastebin.com/edx3XRhi

Comment: You need an instance of type which defines this property. See my edit, just noticed you pasted code.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that isn't giving any more errors.
But I don't recognise that code, how would you go about on inserting a persoon in the database in this way? Thank you so much! :D

Would this work? `context.tblPersoons.InsertOnSubmit`

Comment: I don't think LINQ to SQL was meant to update database (hence **query** in Language INtegrated Query), however you can find some help with those topics on [LINQ to SQL MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386929(v=VS.90).aspx) (*Updating Without Querying* section).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5203/discussion-between-jimmy-keen-and-thomas-schoof)

Comment: Adding **using System.Linq** did it for me.. :)

Comment: "Remove and Sort Usings" just cost me 10 minutes... but the error totally makes sense when you think about it.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 --> Missing System.Linq causes this, and Intellisense won't necessarilly list it automatically.

Answer (score 269):

You may need to add a `using` statement to the file. The default Silverlight class template doesn't include it:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 43):

Make sure these references are included:

- System.Data.Linq
- System.Data.Entity

Then add the using statement

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 28):

You must have forgotten to add a using statement to the file like this:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue with generated strongly typed datasets, the full error message was:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for 
>   source type 'MyApp.InvcHeadDataTable'.  'Where' not found. 
>   Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'row'.

From my code:

```
        var x =
            from row in ds.InvcHead
            where row.Company == Session.CompanyID
            select row;
```

So I did as it suggested and explicitly specified the type:

```
        var x =
            from MyApp.InvcHeadRow row in ds.InvcHead
            where row.Company == Session.CompanyID
            select row;
```

Which worked a treat.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing an equality:

```
var query = (from p in tblPersoon where p.id == 5 select p).Single();
```

`where` clause must result in a boolean.

OR you should not be using `where` at all:

```
var query = (from p in tblPersoon select p).Single();
```

Comment: Thank, I was indeed missing my equality, which was stupid of me. But I now I am getting the following error: Error 1 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'SilverlightApplication1.Web.tblPersoon'.  'Where' not found.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you (like me) that wasted too much time from this error:

I had received the same error: "Could not find implementation of query Pattern for source type 'DbSet'" but the solution for me was fixing a mistake at the DbContext level.

When I created my context I had this:

```
public class ContactContext : DbContext
    {
        public ContactContext() : base() { }

        public DbSet Contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

And my Repository (I was following a Repository pattern in ASP.NET guide) looked like this:

```
public Contact FindById(int id)
    {       
        var contact = from c in _db.Contacts where c.Id == id select c;
        return contact;
    }
```

My issue came from the initial setup of my DbContext, when I used DbSet as a generic instead of the type.

I changed `public DbSet Contacts { get; set; }` to `public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }` and suddenly the query was recognized.

---

This is probably what k.m says in his answer, but since he mentioned `IEnumerable<t>` and not `DbSet<<YourDomainObject>>` I had to dig around in the code for a couple hours to find the line that caused this headache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as described by title, but for me it was simply installing Microsoft access 12.0 oledb redistributable to use with LinqToExcel.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **easiest way to do this** is to convert this IEnumerable into a Queryable

If it is a queryable, then performing queries becomes easy.

Please check this code:

```
var result = (from s in _ctx.ScannedDatas.AsQueryable()
                              where s.Data == scanData
                              select s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                return "Match Found";
```

Make sure you include **System.Linq**.
This way your error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but for me, it was attributed to having a database and a table that were named the same.  When I added the ADO .NET Entity Object to my project, it misgenerated what I wanted in my database context file:

```
// Table
public virtual DbSet<OBJ> OBJs { get; set; }
```

which should've been:

```
public virtual DbSet<OBJ> OBJ { get; set; }
```

And

```
// Database?
public object OBJ { get; internal set; }
```

which I actually didn't really need, so I commented it out.

I was trying to pull in my table like this, in my controller, when I got my error:

```
protected Model1 db = new Model1();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var obj =
        from p in db.OBJ
        orderby p.OBJ_ID descending
        select p;

    return View(obj);
}
```

I corrected my database context and all was fine, after that.

Answer (score 0):

##### I had the same problem, this snippet of code saved my day:

````

`using System.Linq`

`using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

````

Comment: Please only post answers if they add really new and essential information. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8216107/861716) said this *12 years ago*,  and `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` is not essential, only for you.

Comment: @GertArnold how do you know it is essential only for me, may be it will be essential for someone else too some day, besides I'm not using some custom version of C#, I'm just using the one everybody else is using so it cannot be essential only for me

Comment: `using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` has nothing to do with the question. You just happen to use it.