# Auto generated linq class is empty?

Tags: sql, silverlight, linq, class

This is a continuation of my previous question: [Could not find an implementation of the query pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215773/could-not-find-an-implementation-of-the-query-pattern)

I'm trying to insert a new 'Inschrijving' into my database. I try this with the following code:

```
[OperationContract]
public void insertInschrijving(Inschrijvingen inschrijving)
{

    var context = new DataClassesDataContext();

    context.Inschrijvingens.InsertOnSubmit(inschrijving);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

But the context.Inschrijvingens.InsertOnSubmit(inschrijving); gives me the following error:

> cannot convert from 'OndernemersAward.Web.Service.Inschrijvingen' to 'OndernemersAward.Web.Inschrijvingen'

I call the method in my main page:

```
 Inschrijvingen1Client client = new Inschrijvingen1Client();

            Inschrijvingen i = new Inschrijvingen();

            client.insertInschrijvingCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(client_insertInschrijvingCompleted);
            client.insertInschrijvingAsync(i);
```

But as you can see there appears to be something wrong with my Inschrijvingen class, which is auto generated by LINQ. (Auto generated class can be found here: http://pastebin.com/QKuAAKgV)

I'm not entirely sure what is causing this, but I assume it has something to do with the auto generated class not being correct?

Thank you for your time,
Thomas

Comment: `Inschrijvingen` must be defined with the `[DataContract]` attribute.

Comment: Where and how do I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Would that affect the different namespace references? `OndernemersAward.Web.Service.Inschrijvingen` and `OndernemersAward.Web.Inschrijvingen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got *two* `Inschrijvingen` classes - one in the `OndernemersAward.Web.Service` namespace, and one in the `OndernemersAward.Web` namespace.

You *either* need to change the codebase so that you've only got one class, *or* you need to convert from one type to the other.

Comment: Yes indeed this was the problem, I thought I renamed the class but the re-factoring didn't do it's job well enough. Thank you :)