# Linq Selecting rows from a view?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a view in my sql database and it's mapped in my dbml file. Lets call it`userview`

```
using(FooDataContext db = new FooDataContext()){
var users = from ur in db.userview
            where ur.username == "james"   //username is a colomn of userview
            select ur;
}
```

I get the following error

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'TestProject.Models.userview'.  'Select' not found.

Comment: Corrected. I still get the same error though.

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215773 If that post offers and answer and yours is a dupe, then please delete it.

Comment: Have you added using System.Linq to your code file?;

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried to implement it. neither methods suggested in that thread worked. my `userview` doesn't have `where` `select` members, only generic ones like `tostring`, `attach` etc.

Comment: @MikeTWebb Wow, thanks!! That was a huge oversight on my part. Problem fixed.

Comment: should I delete this thread now or should I leave it for future reference for other people?

Comment: Cool deal.  I'm going to Post the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added System.Linq to your code file?