# Could not find an implementation of the query 'Select' not found

Tags: c#, database, linq

My error is:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Database'.  'Select' not found.

My relevent code is:

```
DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();   
var whichUi = from UiType in db.Database
              select  AdvancedUi;
```

I am using the linq import (common answer on other threads).

Comment: Please refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8216107/213550 - db.Database is probably not implementing the `IEnumerable` interface. Also you should note that not only the reference for the library but `using` statement is required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find an implementation of the query pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215773/could-not-find-an-implementation-of-the-query-pattern)

Comment: Sure that you have added using System.Linq;?

Comment: @VMAtm I don't understand the answer in that thread :/.. I'll give the using a try and let you know how it turns out

Comment: @restless By default all my classes are using linq (copy and pasted from the class = using System.Linq; )

Comment: Can you post the code of the `DatabaseEntities.Database`?

Comment: @VMAtm Using a using didn't help (code - using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
            {
                var whichUi = from UiType in db.Database
                              select AdvancedUi;
            })

Comment: @VMAtm There is no code, it's a database? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Am I missing something or should the code say 'select UiType'?

Comment: @DavidG My naming is bad I need to sort it out, I just want to get it working so I can properly start (which is why my query isn't in a method). The box highlighted in red is what I want to select http://prntscr.com/42u4e7

Comment: You need to have 'select UiType.AdvancedUI' and more than likely from db.Database.UiTypes or equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error is that you try to select something from `.Database` directly, not from the table. Instead of this code:

```
from UiType in db.Database
```

try out something like this:

```
from UiType in db.UiTypes
select UiType.AdvancedUi;
```

This should work as the table `UiTypes` will implemet the `IEnumerable` interface.

You should put your table name **after** the in keyword.
`UiType` is just a placeholder, and can be anything you want. Please, pay attention to the `select` clause - you must use the placeholder there, not the table name.

Comment: Pretty much what I wrote in the comments but also the select needs fixing.

Comment: @VMAtm I don't have the option to do that http://prntscr.com/42u7nt Also, why uiTypeObject ; my table isn't called that is there a reason or just a typo?

Comment: @DavidG Please refer to the above comment ><

Comment: Oh, I see! But now it gives this error http://prntscr.com/42u8y7 . I've spelt it correctly ><. @VMAtm P.S. Thank you both for your help

Comment: Like I said above you must put UiType.AdvancedUI

Comment: @DavidG That doesn't work for me http://prntscr.com/42ub8l , http://prntscr.com/42ubcw . I honestly have no clue why :/.. On here it looks so simple.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546142.aspx

Comment: If I'm honest I think you need a course in Linq basics, I'm sure it would solve all your issues.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks a lot! I'll do this a few times to drill it into my head. Thanks again!!

Comment: @DavidG I'd love to be given that oppurtunity but for now it's just me , online resources and stackoverflow :P.

Comment: @user3658489 That's all you need, spend a couple of hours going through an online example (there are lots around) and you will understand each of the components of a Linq query.

Comment: I think that he is missing using system.linq. otherwise how can you select a database directly. intellisense will not even offer you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolved the error by changing:

```
var results = db.MyStoredProc().Select(x => x);
```

Or,

```
var results = from x in db.MyStoredProc()
              select x;
```

To,

```
var results = db.MyStoredProc();
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The whole logic behind the query syntax/fluent syntax is to select an object as a whole or to select a property of an object.

Look at this following query:

```
var result = (from s in _ctx.ScannedDatas.AsQueryable()
                                  where s.Data == scanData
                                  select s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please note that after the *where* clause I am selecting only the *Id property* of the *ScannedData object*.
So to answer your question, if *AdvancedUi* is a property of U*iTypes class* then your query should be more like:

```
var result = from UiType in db.UiTypes
             select UiType.AdvancedUi;
```

Alternatively if you want to return all data from a table say ScannedDatas, then your query will be:

```
var listResult = (from d in _ctx.ScannedDatas
                              select d).ToList();
```

Hope this answers your question my friend.