# Linq Query Pulling Error

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a Linq Query to access data from my Client table. I have the proper Using statement and packages included for Linq. However, when I try to access the client table, I receive the following error.

CS1936 C# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type ''.  '' not found.

```
Client clientID = from c in Client
where c.ID == 1
select c.clientID;
```

Can someone shed some light on the reason I might be receiving this error?

Comment: What type is `Client`? Don't you mean `int clientID = from c in db.Clients...`? The [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215773/could-not-find-an-implementation-of-the-query-pattern) means you're not querying an `IEnumerable<T>`, which would be true if `Client` is a type instead of a client collection.

Comment: what is `Client` it looks like a class.

Comment: Did you google the text of the error message? When I do that, I find a lot of results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is type Client implementing IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: Client is a class, but it is not implementing IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Client is a class, but it is not implementing IEnumerable

[The select clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) calls [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) under the hood. Because Client doesn't implement IEnumerable, you can't use your query against it.