# Error CS1935 'Select' not found

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to read some XML, and I'd like to return all the child elements of the 'all' element. I have this code:

```
    var xmlFile = XDocument.Parse(responseText);

    var elements =
        from el in xmlFile.Elements("all")
        select el;
```

But I'm getting the error:

> 15:15 08/03/2017 Error  : Script (C#.net Script): error CS1935: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.  'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

I've included `using System.Linq` at the top of my project but that doesn't seem to help.

Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: What is your Target .net Framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find an implementation of the query pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215773/could-not-find-an-implementation-of-the-query-pattern)

Comment: Also check if `System.Core` is in the Project references.

Comment: I was missing System.Core, thanks and feel free to add as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your Project references `System.Core`.

*This is a known problem if are trying to use `LINQ` with `.net 2.0`.*