# Entity Framework "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use Entity Framework but I keep getting the error "The underlying provider failed on Open.".  I am storing the password within the code at the getConnectionString function provides a valid connection string and I know it works because I use that function throughout (albeit throughout my non-Entity Framework programs).  I have Customer defined in my Model1 file.  Customer is a database.

```
// gets valid connection string
string cs = getConnectionString();

var entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = cs;
entityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata = "res://*";


CUSTEntities1 CustContext = new  CUSTEntities1(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());

var q = (from i in CustContext.Customers
         where i.CustLen == 15
         select new CustomerClass
         {
            fid1 = i.fid1,
            fid21 = i.fid2,
            custlen = (int)i.CustLen
          }).ToList<CustomerClass>();
```

I am new to Entity Framework and am trying to make a simple test app to help me understand it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have rebuilt the project from scratch to make sure that I had all the parts I needed for EF.

Comment: Is 'Customer' an IEnumerable type?
Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215773/could-not-find-an-implementation-of-the-query-pattern

Comment: I saw that post and tried to model after it without success

Comment: Come to think of it, you should be careful with the latest edit. It changes the question and should probably be a new one now (in which you might want to provide your current `CUSTEntities1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be querying from the context, EF doesn't know what to do with the class alone.

The query would need to start with

```
from customer in context.Customers
```

Since it seems that you are using a model- or database-first approach, the context should already contain a DbSet. In your case it's in `CUSTEntities1`.

Comment: I tried that but a.Customers is not available to me.

Comment: @Missy How did you create the model?

Comment: Yes -- I am using a database first approach.  I don't understand why Customers is not available to me.  Your advise about the variable names is good.

Comment: @Missy In this case, you might want to recreate the Model (And just to make sure, `context.Customer` is not available either?)

Comment: Okay.  I will do that.  Context.Customer is not available either - correct.