# Get Row Count of Dbset in DbContext dynamicly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I have a form that pass a instance of my `DbContext` and a Entity of Table to it as below :

```
public frm_foo(DbContext DatabaseContext, DbSet TableEntity)
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           var res =GetRowCount(DatabaseContext,TableEntity);
        }
```

And call form contractor by:

```
new frm_foo(dbContext, dbContext.Set<IpRoom>()).ShowDialog();
```

The Context contain a `IpRoom` table.

I want to get Count of row from in a function that send the `DbContext` and `Dbset` instance to it as below :

```
public int GetRowCount(DbContext DatabaseContext, DbSet TableEntity)
   {
       var countVal = (from a in DatabaseContext.Set(TableEntity.GetType())
                        select a).Count();
       return countVal;
   }
```

But Got error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'DbSet'.  'Select' not found.

While `DatabaseContext.Set(TableEntity.GetType())` return a Dbset! Anybody know whats my wrong? Thanks in advance

**Ps**: I dont want use `SqlQuery`, Something like:

```
var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.IpRoom";
var total = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).Single();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find an implementation of the query pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215773/could-not-find-an-implementation-of-the-query-pattern)

Comment: It will be interesting to see the intended usage of this method, i.e. `GetRowCount(context, ???)`

Comment: @IvanStoev : Whats `???` Ivan? do you mean pass one parameter to function?

Comment: No :) The question was how do you get the `DbSet` in order to pass it to the method. Just wondering why you need that method at all, because for instance `context.Logs.Count()` will easily do the same.

Comment: Aha :) you meas maybe could pass the name of `Dbset` instead of instance of that yes?

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure. Now I see your update, and somehow can solve the `Count` issue, but note that the non generic `DbSet` is almost unusable. You can't write normal LINQ against it, neither `ToList` etc. If you are absolutely sure the problem is just the `Count()`, I guess we could help.

Comment: I want use `count` and could filter some row of DbSet

Comment: Then probably you should try [DynamicLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic) package. It contains custom extension method `Count` defined for `IQueryable`, hence can be used with `DbSet` as well as other `IQueryable` custom methods which can be useful for your scenario.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks Ivan..your hint about `GetRowCount(context, ???)` help me to find answer my question

Answer (score 1):

`DbSet` does not implement IQueryable, `DbSet<T>` does.  eg

```
public static int GetRowCount<T>(DbContext DatabaseContext, DbSet<T> TableEntity)
{
    var countVal = TableEntity.Count();
    return countVal;
}
```

Comment: it generate this error: **The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbSet<TEntity>'**

Comment: Right.  T should be an Entity type defined in your DbContext subclass.  Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to accomplish in more detail.

Comment: I explain more in question David. Could you please see that?

Comment: Read the question again.  Still have no idea what you're trying to do.  Perhaps a short, complete repro would help.

Comment: in fact i was do some action on a table in `Dbcontex` in a form...For example count of table row...or filter some row and show it to end user...because of that i send a instance of `dbcontext` and `dbset` that witch must give count or filter from that

Comment: Post a short, complete repro where you try to call the function in my answer.  It should allow you to get the count of any entity in your DbContext.

Comment: I just copy and past your code to my project...Compile and see above error

Comment: What is the type parameter T you are using?

Comment: A Entity in DbContex. In my case the `IpRoom` table

Comment: Then you'll need to produce a repro.  That error shouldn't occur when T is an Entity.

Comment: I thing when send a entity to other form as some thing like `dbContext.Set<IpRoom>()` , the new form recive that entity as a instanse variable of DbSet class only. And its normal that dont work as orginal entity...i think we must find a way to acess the entity in Dbcontext dynamily or by name to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

To get generic row count I use the following method.

```
public static int GetRowCount<T>(DbContext context)
    {
        // Get the generic type definition
        var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(
            nameof(DbContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Build a method with the specific type argument you're interested in
        method = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

        var iEnumerable = method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable<T>;

        return (iEnumerable ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).Count();
    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure if you have T you can write it shorter:
```public static int GetRowCount<T>(DbContext context) => context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Count();```

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like this one to know if the table have no elements and needs to be seeded with data to have something to work with:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFCoreTutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            using (var context = new Data.SchoolContext())
            {
                var studentsCount = context.Students.Count();

                if (studentsCount == 0)
                {
                    // Seed all your starting data now
                    var student = new Model.Student()
                    {
                        Name = "Ali",
                    };

                    context.Students.Add(student);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SchoolContext is derived from DbContext.

Answer (score -2):

Add a class to your project as blow:

```
namespace System.Data.Entity
{
  public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions
  {
    public static IEnumerable<object> AsEnumerable(this DbSet set)
    {
      foreach (var entity in set)
        yield return entity;
    }
  }
}
```

This class add a Generic method `AsEnumerable` to `DbSet` instance and when you want to use it for example for *Count*:

```
 var count = (from a in TableEntity.AsEnumerable() select a).Count();
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, as it will cause all the entities in the DbSet to be loaded into memory instead of running the count on in the DB.

Comment: This is notably slow.