# Could not find implementation of query pattern for source type: select not found while deserializing service response

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, deserialization

This is not a duplicate question, I checked all the available questions on the same subject.

I'm trying to consume a service which is WSDL.

Now I want to return the list of particular field from the response and below is what I tried:

[image]

What is the best way to return a list of 'PreferredFullName' from the response?

Comment: Is response type an IEnumerable or something like that or is it just an object ( not a collection )?

Comment: @m.rogalski Its just an object

Comment: So why do you use Linq? Just use `var q = new PersonDetailsBO { PrefferedFullName = t1.PrefferedFullName };`

Comment: @@m.rogalski I need to return list of PreffredFullName

Comment: Two things: 1. paste code as text , not as an image. 2. You REALLY should remove these private data from your question. In fact, I did the last thing for you.

Comment: Good job @Cody!

Comment: *This is not a duplicate question, I checked all the available questions on the same subject.* - then please **show what you tried** that did not work.  In order to help you, we need to see a [mcve] -- some code we can review and, ideally, debug,  As it is, with only a bitmap image of an error, all we can do is run Google and find: [Could not find an implementation of the query pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8215773).  See also [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for putting code as image. Anyways, I could figure out the solution by `response.responsenote.Select()`